# How to shade a png image for iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImage that is displaying a grayscale button. Is there a way to "shade" the image with a color when i draw it? So i could effectively have 1 grayscale button image, but have any color button? I would also like to have the transparent pixels stay transparent if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question making sense to those who are viewing it?

Comment: Yes.  What is the image?

Comment: Sure. Like when Ted Turner colorized all those classic black&white MGM, RKO, and Warner Bros films.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to use Quartz 2D with the following steps:

1. Create a `CGImage` for the PNG background with `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`, or use `UIImage` as usual and grab a reference to the Quartz image data using the `CGImage` property of the `UIImage`.
2. Set the blend mode on the image with `CGContextSetBlendMode`. The mode you're after is probably `kCGBlendModeOverlay`.
3. Create a new single-tone `CGImage` for the shading layer.
4. Use `CGContextDrawImage` to composite the shading layer over the background layer.

Detailed instructions on how to do this are available in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide, in the section titled ["Using Blend Modes with Images"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBIJEFG).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent hours looking for this solution. I'll try it out as soon as i get off of work. Thanks again!